# Changing Django ManyToMany "through" value across model inheritance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

This is a simplified part of my model that causes me some troubles:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    node_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    links = models.ManyToManyField(
            "self",
            through='NodeLinks',
            blank=True,
            through_fields=('source', 'target'))

class NodeLinks(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='r_source', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='r_target', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('source', 'target',),)


class Tag(Node):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class TagLinks(NodeLinks):
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

TagLinks._meta.get_field('target').related_model = Tag
TagLinks._meta.get_field('source').related_model = Tag
```

If I only want to retrieve `Tag` objects for example by executing this query: `TagLinks.objects.all().values_list('target__label', flat=True)`

I got `NodeLinks` objects which don't have the `label` field instead of `TagLinks` objects.

To simplify, currently `Tag.links.through` is defined as `NodeLinks` . Is it possible to change it to `TagLinks`?

Answer (score 0):

> To simplify, currently `Tag.links.through` is defined as `NodeLinks`. Is it possible to change it to `TagLinks`?

Yes, You should add `related_name` attribute to both `ManyToManyField` fields, which specifies the name of the reverse relation. Change it to `related_tags` for `Tag.links` and `related_nodes` for `Node.links`.

Also use `symmetrical=False` attribute in both the fields. This attribute specifies whether the relation is symmetrical or not. Since a `Tag` can have multiple links to another Tag, but a `Tag` can only be linked once, the relation is not symmetrical, so:

```py
class Node(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    node_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    links = models.ManyToManyField(
            "self",
            through='NodeLinks',
            blank=True,
            related_name='related_nodes',
            symmetrical=False)

class NodeLinks(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='r_source', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='r_target', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('source', 'target',),)


class Tag(Node):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    links = models.ManyToManyField(
            "self",
            through='TagLinks',
            blank=True,
            related_name='related_tags',
            symmetrical=False)

class TagLinks(NodeLinks):
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('source', 'target',),)
```

By doing above changes, you should be able to retrieve Tag objects using:

```py
TagLinks.objects.all().values_list('target__label', flat=True)
```

> **Note:** Generally Django models don't require `s` to be added as suffix, so it is better to name it as `NodeLink` and `TagLink` instead of <s>`NodeLinks`</s> and <s>`TagLinks`</s> respectively.

Comment: thanks for your answer and advice, however django return me this error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'links' in class 'Tag' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Node'`

Comment: @OlivierB. The error is simple and it is because you have two fields `links` one in `Node` and another one in `Tag` model, so try to change field name to `tag_links` in `Tag` model which inherits the `Node` model then run `makemigrations and migrate` commands as usual, it will resolve the issue.